# Mysql NOT IN and NOT EXIST the same?

Tags: mysql

I sometimes interchanged the use of `NOT IN` and `NOT EXIST` in my sql queries and both  yield the same result. Is the logic behind the `NOT EXIST` the same as `NOT IN`? Because I think that `NOT IN`... (is being evaluated as "OR" inside the subqueries) is equal to `NOT EXIST` (which is also evaluated as "OR")? Or am i missing something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [DELETE Difference NOT IN vs NOT EXISTS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212704/delete-difference-not-in-vs-not-exists)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This article may be of interest to you:

- [**NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL: MySQL**](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/)

In a nutshell, `NOT IN` is slightly different from `NOT EXISTS` in the way the two handle `NULL` values returned by the subquery.

If there are no `NULL` values, they both perform a kind on `NESTED LOOP ANTI JOIN`, but `NOT IN` is a little bit more efficient.

Answer (score 6):

No, they are not the same. The IN function translates to a series of OR statements. Typically this trips people up when they use a subquery in the IN function and that query returns at least one null value. E.g. `Col Not In( Select Foo From Bar )`. This compares `Col <> Foo` for each row. If one of the values of Foo is null, you get `Col <> NULL` and the entire statement returns false resulting in no rows.

Exists simply determines if any rows in the subquery are returned (Not Exists being that no rows can be returned). The Select clause is entirely ignored.

---

Example:

```
Create Table Test ( Id int not null )
Insert Test ( 1 )
Insert Test ( 2 )
Insert Test ( 3 )

Create Table Bar  ( Foo int null )
Insert Bar ( Null )
Insert Bar ( 1 )
Insert Bar ( 2 )
```

The following will result in no rows since we are effectively doing the comparison of `Not( Id = Null Or Id = 1 Or Id = 2 )`

```
Select Id
From Test
Where Id Not In( Select Foo From Bar )
```

The following however will return one row

```
Select Id
From Test
Where Not Exists( Select 1 From Bar Where Foo = Id )
```

In the above query, I will get Id = 3.

Comment: but why is the result always the same?

Comment: when would the result not be the same?

Comment: @newbie - No. They are not always the same. If in our example above, there is a value of `Foo` that is null, our Not In expression will result in the outer query returning no rows. However, if we are using a correlated subquery with exists (e.g. `Exists( Select * From Bar Where Foo = OuterTableCol)`), and one of the values of Foo is null and none of values match our OuterTableCol, the outer query will return rows.

Comment: @newbie - I have expanded my answer to illustrate how you could get a different result.

Answer (score 2):

Both will give you the same results.  The NOT EXISTS is a correlated sub-query, it is joined to the main query.  In the example below, the NOT EXISTS should perform faster on a large dataset.

Find products without orders.

```
select *
  from Products
 where ProductId NOT IN (select ProductId FROM Orders)

select *
  from Products
 where NOT EXISTS (select 1 FROM Orders WHERE orders.ProductId = Products.Id)
```

Comment: Not true if ProductId contains nulls.

Comment: @Thomas - Good point, thanks for reminding me about the possibility of null.

Answer (score 0):

Not Exist and Not in works same way.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE Test ( Id INT NOT NULL );
INSERT INTO Test VALUES ( 1 );
INSERT INTO Test VALUES ( 2 );
INSERT INTO Test VALUES( 3 );

CREATE TABLE Bar  ( Foo INT NULL );
INSERT INTO Bar VALUES( NULL );
INSERT INTO Bar VALUES ( 1 );
INSERT INTO Bar VALUES( 2 );
```

Executing:

```
SELECT Id
FROM Test
WHERE Id NOT IN( SELECT Foo FROM Bar WHERE foo=id );
```

---> It will give the output as 3

And executing:

```
SELECT Id
FROM Test
WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT foo FROM Bar WHERE Foo = Id );
```

---> It will also give the output as 3