# MYSQL Regex Negative Lookahead alternative

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I'm doing a query on a postcode/zip code field.
I've been doing a bit of research and negative lookaheads aren't supported:

> "MySQL supports POSIX regular expressions, not PCRE"

Is there an alternative solution to the below, using the regular expressions supported by MYSQL?

`(?i)^W(?!C)` -- this is the solution in PHP

And an example query to the database

```
select postcode from `postcodes` WHERE LOWER(postcode) REGEXP '^W(?!C)'
```

Comment: You want to get postcodes that start with 'W', followed by something other than 'C'?

Comment: MariaDB 10.0 does handle PCRE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, you may use

```
WHERE postcode REGEXP '^W([^C]|$)'
```

`([^C]|$)` matches any char but `C` or end of string. Also, no need to use `TOLOWER` as the regex search is case insensitive by default.

See the [online tests](http://rextester.com/WUK21683):

```
SELECT 'wc' REGEXP '^W([^C]|$)'; // => 0
SELECT 'wR' REGEXP '^W([^C]|$)'; // => 1
SELECT 'w' REGEXP '^W([^C]|$)';  // => 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can **inverse the regex** of what you want to achieve and use **NOT REGEXP**

```
SELECT postcode from `postcodes`
WHERE postcode NOT REGEXP '^w(c|$)'
```

The piece of code above is about a **single character** as asked in the question.
For people who end up here in this thread and look for a negative lookahead with a **full word** it is also possible in contrast with the other answer from @Wiktor Stribiżew

```
-- So not the word 'not_this_word' or end of the string '$'
SELECT postcode from `postcodes`
WHERE postcode NOT REGEXP '^w(not_this_word|$)'
```

OR you can go for a subquery with NOT IN

```
SELECT postcode from `postcodes`
WHERE postcode NOT IN (
    SELECT postcode from `postcodes` WHERE postcode REGEXP '^w(not_this_word|$)'
)
```

Comment: Relevant reading: [Mysql NOT IN and NOT EXIST the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5780096/2943403)

Comment: I think your expression isn't respecting the full requirement in the question.  The OP needs to find all postcodes where the postcode DOES start with `W` and the second character is not `C` (or might not exist).  Right?

Comment: OK, I could write '^wc' instead of '^ wnot_this_word'. But I just wanted to show that my answer does not limits itself to 1 single character 'c' but you can even add a whole word which may not come after the letter 'w'. But I will update my answer some more.