# Understanding how to design MySQL indexes for good performance

Tags: mysql

Through trial and error, I've arrived at a good index for this query, but I'd really like to understand why this and only this index helps, and how to avoid having to repeat the t&e next time.

The InnoDB table structure for a log table is:
[image: Log table structure]

This is my query—it's looking for all users who have one kind of action in the log, but *not* another kind of action. It's also restricting to certain values of `org` and a certain date range.

```
SELECT DISTINCT USER AS 'Dormant Users'
FROM db.log
WHERE `action` = @a1
  AND `org` = @orgid
  AND `logdate` >= @startdate
  AND USER NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT USER
             FROM db.log
            WHERE `action` = @a2
              AND `org` = @orgid
              AND `logdate` >= @startdate)
;
```

With no indexes, this takes about 21 seconds, and `EXPLAIN` shows this:

[image: EXPLAIN with no indexes]

So, I thought having an index on `org`, `logdate`, and `action` might help. And it does—if I create an index on those columns in *that precise order*, the query time is reduced to about 0.3s, and the `EXPLAIN` output is now:

[image: EXPLAIN with good index]

But, if I change the order of the columns within the index, or even just add another, unrelated index (say on the `user` column), the query takes about 2 seconds.

So, how can I understand and even design the index to perform well based on that query, and avoid the rather degenerate case of adding another index and harming performance? Or is it just a case of test and see what works?

Comment: Can we reject the premise of the question on account of the fact that an alternative query would likely be faster?

Comment: You should focus on writing a good query rather than indexing a bad one. That is a terrible query. If you want your queries to go fast, don't use sub-queries and don't use `NOT IN`.

Comment: this might be a better fit for DBA stackexhange

Answer (score 3):

My answer is not the answer because it is not about how to set the index but how to write your query to make it more efficient.

Avoid using `NOT IN` if the subquery is not a small table :

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT l1.USER AS 'Dormant Users'
FROM db.log l1
WHERE `action` = @a1
  AND `org` = @orgid
  AND `logdate` >= @startdate
  AND NOT EXISTS  (SELECT 1
             FROM db.log l2
            WHERE l1.`user` = l2.`user`
              AND l1.`org` = l2.`org`
              AND l2.`action` = @a2
              AND l2.`logdate` >= @startdate)
;
```

**EDIT** : I removed the explanation link as it is not what I thought. I am only a skilled developer and not a DBA. Thus, I have optimized a lot of queries and I always have had better results with `NOT EXISTS` than `NOT IN` when volumes get hihg. But I am not able to argue about the internal reason (and I guess it depends on the RDBMS)

Comment: Can you reference what is so bad about `NOT IN` rather than `NOT EXISTS`?

Comment: Just keep in mind that ```NOT IN``` is evil :). You can read from this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780096/mysql-not-in-and-not-exist-the-same

Comment: Is it evil or simply inefficient?

Comment: It is evil only because it is inefficient. A query aims to be efficient. The ```NOT IN``` syntax is easy to understand, to use ... but in the end they always become the queries that kill your db perf, To sum up, ```NOT IN``` is the dark side of SQL

Comment: @OlivierDepriester actually the summary of the article quoted in that topic says the opposite.

Comment: With no index, that takes 16 seconds on my dataset and with the `org_logdate_action` index it's just over 1 second, so three times slower than with `NOT IN`. The summary of the answer you linked to specifically says that, ignoring `NULL` values, `NOT IN` is just a slightly more efficient version of `NOT EXISTS`. The final line of the full article says "That's why the best way to search for missing values in MySQL is using a LEFT JOIN / IS NULL or NOT IN rather than NOT EXISTS." So, yes, a better query in place of indexes to make this work well would be great. But is this one really better?

Comment: @OlivierDepriester See comments above from me an Gnudiff. Can you clarify your answer which references an article that contradicts what you wrote? Since it's the top answer so far, it might be confusing for people. I also did some testing with the profiler on the 3 main approaches, and get some very odd results—like the profiler says the query took 1.7s but the wall clock says 20s. So I will do what Gnudiff said and try a DBA stack instead.

Answer (score 0):

...or with an outer join...

```
SELECT DISTINCT user 
           FROM log x
           LEFT
           JOIN log y
             ON y.user = x.user
            AND y.org = x.org
            AND y.action = @a2
            AND y.logdate > = @startdate
          WHERE x.action` = @a1
            AND x.org = @orgid
            AND x.logdate >= @startdate
            AND y.user IS NULL;
```

I'm not too hot on indexing, but I'd start with (org, action, logdate)